# Error: "ValueError: Input 0 of layer 'dense_1' is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=0"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i am trying to build a vision model but I'm have issue with this Transformer class.
The error occurs when using a Dense layer in a deep learning model. The error message states that the input shape provided to the Dense layer does not meet the required minimum dimensions. Instead of the expected minimum of 2 dimensions, the input has 0 dimensions.

iv tried different ways of reshaping but keep getting the same issues

> "PS E:\Portfolio\Image_Classification> &
> C:/Users/TomMc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe
> e:/Portfolio/Image_Classification/CancerImages.py TensorFlow version:
> 2.12.0 x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3) - y_train shape: (50000, 1) x_test shape: (10000, 32, 32, 3) - y_test shape: (10000, 1)
> Hyperparameters configured! Data augmentation configured! MLP function
> implemented! Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "e:\Portfolio\Image_Classification\CancerImages.py", line 148, in
>
> vit_model = VisionTransformer(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "e:\Portfolio\Image_Classification\CancerImages.py", line 106, in
> **init**
> self.transformer_blocks = [TransformerBlock(projection_dim, num_heads, transformer_units, dropout_rate) for _ in
> range(transformer_layers)]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "e:\Portfolio\Image_Classification\CancerImages.py", line 106, in
>
> self.transformer_blocks = [TransformerBlock(projection_dim, num_heads, transformer_units, dropout_rate) for _ in
> range(transformer_layers)]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "e:\Portfolio\Image_Classification\CancerImages.py", line 132, in
> **init**
> self.mlp = mlp(projection_dim, transformer_units, dropout_rate)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "e:\Portfolio\Image_Classification\CancerImages.py", line 56, in
> mlp
> x = layers.Dense(units, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(x)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\TomMc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py",
> line 70, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   File "C:\Users\TomMc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py",
> line 253, in assert_input_compatibility
> raise ValueError( ValueError: Input 0 of layer "dense_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=0. Full
> shape received: () PS E:\Portfolio\Image_Classification> "

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras

print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)

# Prepare the data
num_classes = 100
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()

print(f"x_train shape: {x_train.shape} - y_train shape: {y_train.shape}")
print(f"x_test shape: {x_test.shape} - y_test shape: {y_test.shape}")

# Configure the hyperparameters
learning_rate = 0.001
weight_decay = 0.0001
batch_size = 256
num_epochs = 100
image_size = 72  # We'll resize input images to this size
patch_size = 6  # Size of the patches to be extracted from the input images
num_patches = (image_size // patch_size) ** 2
projection_dim = 64
num_heads = 4
transformer_units = [
    projection_dim * 2,
    projection_dim,
]  # Size of the transformer layers
transformer_layers = 8
mlp_head_units = [2048, 1024]  # Size of the dense layers of the final classifier

print("Hyperparameters configured!")

# Start of the block you can comment in/out
# Use data augmentation
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Normalization(),
        layers.Resizing(image_size, image_size),
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.02),
        layers.RandomZoom(height_factor=0.2, width_factor=0.2),
    ],
    name="data_augmentation",
)
# Compute the mean and the variance of the training data for normalization.
data_augmentation.layers[0].adapt(x_train)

print("Data augmentation configured!")
# End of the block you can comment in/out

# Implement MLP function
def mlp(x, hidden_units, dropout_rate):
    for units in hidden_units:
        x = layers.Dense(units, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    return x




print("MLP function implemented!")


# Patch creation layer
class PatchCreation(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size):
        super(PatchCreation, self).__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding='VALID'
        )
        patch_dim = patches.shape[-1]
        num_patches = (images.shape[1] // self.patch_size) * (images.shape[2] // self.patch_size)
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, num_patches, patch_dim])
        return patches


# Patch encoding layer
class PatchEncoding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim):
        super(PatchEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)

    def call(self, patches):
        encoded_patches = self.projection(patches)
        return encoded_patches


# Vision Transformer model
class VisionTransformer(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, image_size, patch_size, num_patches, projection_dim, num_heads, transformer_units, transformer_layers, mlp_head_units, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(VisionTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.patch_creation = PatchCreation(patch_size)
        self.patch_encoding = PatchEncoding(num_patches, projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim)
        self.transformer_blocks = [TransformerBlock(projection_dim, num_heads, transformer_units, dropout_rate) for _ in range(transformer_layers)]
        self.mlp_head = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim, activation=tf.nn.gelu)
        self.mlp_dropout = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.classification_head = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, inputs):
        patches = self.patch_creation(inputs)
        encoded_patches = self.patch_encoding(patches)
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=tf.shape(encoded_patches)[1], delta=1)
        position_embeddings = self.position_embedding(positions)
        encoded_patches += position_embeddings
        for transformer_block in self.transformer_blocks:
            encoded_patches = transformer_block(encoded_patches)
        representation = tf.reduce_mean(encoded_patches, axis=1)
        features = self.mlp_head(representation)
        features = self.mlp_dropout(features)
        outputs = self.classification_head(features)
        return outputs

# Transformer block
class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, projection_dim, num_heads, transformer_units, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=projection_dim)
        self.attention_dropout = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.attention_normalization = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.mlp = mlp(projection_dim, transformer_units, dropout_rate)
        self.mlp_dropout = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.mlp_normalization = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

    def call(self, inputs):
        attention_output = self.attention(inputs, inputs)
        attention_output = self.attention_dropout(attention_output)
        attention_output = self.attention_normalization(inputs + attention_output)
        mlp_output = self.mlp(attention_output)
        mlp_output = self.mlp_dropout(mlp_output)
        block_output = self.mlp_normalization(attention_output + mlp_output)
        return block_output



# Create the Vision Transformer model instance
vit_model = VisionTransformer(
    num_classes=num_classes,
    image_size=image_size,
    patch_size=patch_size,
    num_patches=num_patches,
    projection_dim=projection_dim,
    num_heads=num_heads,
    transformer_units=transformer_units,
    transformer_layers=transformer_layers,
    mlp_head_units=mlp_head_units,
    dropout_rate=0.1
)

print("Vision Transformer model created!")

# Compile the model
vit_model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

# Train the model
vit_model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_accuracy = vit_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print(f"Test Loss: {test_loss}")
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy}")

print("Done!")
```